# Symfony entity with Datetime

Tags: php, datetime, symfony

I would like to create a html choice field with datetime entries of the last edits made. When taking any other fields in the database this works, with datetime it doesn't.

In the formtype I have

```
class MemberlistType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('CreatedAt', 'entity', array(
                'mapped' => false,
                'class' => 'TestProject\TestBundle\Entity\Memberlist',
                'property' => 'created_at'
                ))
```

`

In the view I have

```
{{form_label(form.children.memberlists[0].children.CreatedAt}}
{{form_widget(form.children.memberlists[0].children.CreatedAt}}
{{form_errors(form.children.memberlists[0].children.CreatedAt)}}
```

And I get:

```
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Catchable Fatal Error: Object 
of class DateTime could not be converted to string in /var/www/symfony/vendor/symfony/symfony
/src/Symfony/Component/Translation/Translator.php line 188") in 
TestprojectTestBundle:Default:updateData.html.twig at line 77
```

How can I convert this datetime to string in an easy way?

Answer (score 1):

You have this error because entity try view name as string, but object \DateTime not have __toString method.

Best solution - create custom view transformer.

Answer (score 1):

You could call the twig filter "date":

```
{{form_label(form.children.memberlists[0].children.CreatedAt|date("m/d/Y")}}
{{form_widget(form.children.memberlists[0].children.CreatedAt|date("m/d/Y")}}
{{form_errors(form.children.memberlists[0].children.CreatedAt|date("m/d/Y"))}}
```

Edit, i misread the question...
Like ZhukV said, you need a ViewTransformer:

```
namespace My\Bundle\Form\Transformers;

class DateToStringTransformer
{
    public function transform($dateObj)
    {
        if (null === $dateObj) {
            return "";
        }

        return $dateObj->format('m/d/Y');
    }

    public function reverseTransform($date)
    {
        if ($date === "") {
            return null;
        }
        $dateObj = new \DateTime($issue);

        return $dateObj;
    }
}
```

then call it in your form:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $transformer = new new DateToStringTransformer();
    $builder
        ->add(
            $builder->create('CreatedAt', 'entity', array(
                'mapped' => false,
                'class' => 'TestProject\TestBundle\Entity\Memberlist',
                'property' => 'created_at'
            ))->addViewTransformer($transformer)
        )
```

More info here: http://symfony.com/fr/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html

Comment: No, then I get 'Object of class Symfony\Component\Form\FormView could not be converted to string'

Comment: Didn't work. I got FatalErrorException: Error: Call to undefined method TestProject\TestBundle\Entity\Memberlist::format() but i found another method

Comment: Could you explain your method to fix this ?

Comment: Yes will do, but I have to wait 8 hours before I can post an answer to my question. Its because I have less than 15 credits here